# MS Access Version of Case When

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, case

Was Try to figure out how to write this in MS Access I saw a forum talk about IIF statements but I couldn't really get it to work.

```
SELECT 
       case 
         when count(case when f.preferred_flg = 'Y' then 1 end) > 0 then 'Y'
         else 'N'
       end as "Indicator = Y",
       case 
         when count(case when f.preferred_flg = 'N' then 1 end) > 0 then 'Y'
         else 'N'
       end as "Indicator = N"
  FROM il_Product f
```

Comment: I think... `iif(count(iff(f.prefered_flg='Y',1) > 0,'Y','N') as [Indicator = Y],`

Comment: The Case statement can only be used in VBA code for MS Access.  Is that what you're doing?

Comment: In Access, use `iif()` https://www.techonthenet.c(om/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

Answer (score 0):

`iif` is the MS Access equivalent, and other responses here should help you get that working. But there is another option which I've just stumbled upon: `SWITCH`. I guess I didn't previously know about this as I haven't used MS Access seriously since Access 2003. Here's how to call it:

```
SWITCH(<condition1>, <output1> [, <condition2>, <output 2>, ... ])
```

If none of the conditions are true, it will return `NULL`. If you want a default value make the last pair of parameters `TRUE, <Default Output>`.

When I wrote this the Microsoft Support article on this was [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379).

Answer (score 0):

It can be done much simpler:

```
SELECT 
    IIF(ABS(SUM(f.preferred_flg = 'Y')) > 0, 'Y', 'N') AS [Indicator = Y],
    IIF(ABS(SUM(f.preferred_flg = 'N')) > 0, 'Y', 'N') AS [Indicator = N]
FROM 
    il_Product AS f
```